# Any composition of the Finsler-Minkowski norm giving a Morse function?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, morse-theory

Given a **Finsler-Minkowski** norm $F$ on $R^n$, let $\mathfrak{F}=\{\Sigma_r\}_{r\geq0}$, where $\Sigma_r=\{y\in R^n: F(y)=r\}$, be a partition of $R^n$. There exists any (infinitely) smooth **Morse** function $f:R^n\to R$ such that $f^{-1}(c)=\Sigma_r$ (that is gave the same partition)?

FYI:

1. A function $F:R^n\to R$ that is (infinitely) smooth on $R^n\backslash 0$ is called a **Finsler-Minkowski** norm if $F(y)>0$, for $y\neq 0$, $F(\lambda y)=\lambda F(y)$, for $\lambda\in R>0$, and if $E:=\frac12 F^2$, then $\forall y\in R^n\backslash 0$, $g_y:=E''(y):R^n\times R^n\to R$ is non-degenerate.
2. $f:R^n\to R$ is called a **Morse** function if all of the critical points are non-degenerate, that is the Hessian of $f$ at each critical point is non-degenerate.

As $g_y$ is non-degenerate for nonzero values of $y$, one candidate could be the composition of $g_y$ with some other functions like Bump or ....

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think Minkowski is great tag. Minkowski did [quite a few things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Minkowski#See_also).

Comment: @pjs36 What could be a more suitable tag?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really know anything about this topic (although it looks fine to me, what you have) -- I'm just pointing out that a tag simply called [tag:minkowski] could refer to any number of very different things, which is not a desirable property for a tag to have.